# Adding items to a sale - passing item objects in to ArrayList in constructor - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am attempting to model an online shop with features such as selling, refunding etc. I have the code working but only with 1 item per sale. However I am wanting to many items per sale as would a normal shopping experience.

I thought about using perhaps a normal array, but then changed to an ArrayList; however I can't think of a proper way in which I can pass through Items into this array and how it should be laid out in the code. I have seen others ask this type of question, but I haven't been able to find much luck with an actual object being passed.

A standard item is extended into either Book, Map or DVD, with a book being defined as such:

```
Item book = new Book(40,4, 23.99, "G R R Martin", "One of the Game of Thrones Books", 893);
```

**Book constructor**

```
public Book(int stockNum, int totalSold, double cost, String author, String title, int pages) {
        super(stockNum, totalSold, cost);
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.pages = pages;
    }
```

**Sale.java** *- Code has been simplified for demonstration purposes*

```
public class NewSale {
    private static numSales = 0;
    private int customerId, saleId;
    private List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    private double subtotal;

    public NewSale(List<Item> itemList, int customerId) {
        this.saleTime = saleTime;
        this.customerId = customerId;

        this.itemList = itemList;

        for (Item i : itemList) {
            this.subtotal += i.getCost();
        }

        numSales++;
        this.saleId = numSales;
    }
```

Comment: So, what is the problem with the posted code?

Comment: I'm wanting to know if it is the right way to go about it, or whether I am doing it completely wrong?
Thinking that I should go through a middle basket case

Comment: Well, a "basket" is really just a list of items, isn't it?  So you're pretty much already headed down that route anyway, and it's a perfectly reasonable way to go.

Comment: I was wondering more like, how to get the list of items into the constructor in a way that wasn't verbose and OTT.

If I were setting up an example Sale just as proof of concept, my line of code would be huge would it not? Assuming that I haven't created a bunch of objects in the Item list itself...

I shall have a think about it further.